# adding buttons to JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager

I've got this code that creates buttons from A till Z and then when the button is clicked a `JOption` message appears saying which button is clicked (I haven't added that part of the code yet)

But my problem is that I don't know how to add the button code to an panel and then display it. Because I want to create 4 panels for each section of the hangman game

- Panel 1 = buttons in a flow layout
- Panel 2 = images of the hangman
- Panel 3 = the hidden word
- Panel 4 = control buttons

Can someone please help?

This is my code so far :

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Hangman extends JFrame{

    public Hangman(){

        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        for(char i = 'A'; i <= 'Z'; i++){
            String buttonText = new Character(i).toString();
            JButton button = getButton(buttonText);
            add(button);
        }
    }
    public JButton getButton(final String text){
    final JButton button = new JButton(text);
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

            }
        });
        return button;
    }
    public static void main (String [] args){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Provide ASCII art of the GUI as it should appear by default, as well as how it will look when stretched to extra width and height (to show which components get the extra).

Comment: Just a tip: I would rename the `getButton` method to `createButton`. Typically a getter simply returns an existing object. Seldom it creates one, so the name is very confusing

Answer (score 0):

i think you forget call setSize method

```
public static void main (String [] args){
   JFrame frame = new JFrame();
   frame.setSize(200,300);
   frame.setVisible(true);
   }
```